# Speakers has a lower volume than actual volume output from system

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, speakers

This started happening a while ago. I realized the volume I hear is very low. I opened up the volume control panel and I see the speakers are outputting a lower volume than "System" (it is only lowering System not other applications):

[image]

Not only that, some applications that have sounds won't show on the panel and the speakers are not outputting those audio. Every time I have to re-enable the audio driver (Intel(R) Display Audio) to make it work.

What is causing this behavior? How can I fix this? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: start by going into control pannel sounds and looking at (double click) your speakers, in both levels and check enhancements. Then http://superuser.com/questions/504004/windows-8-turns-program-sound-volume-down-randomly & http://superuser.com/questions/499048/what-does-the-grey-peak-mean-in-volume-mixer & http://superuser.com/questions/599647/computer-playing-sounds-but-not-showing-action-on-volume-mixer & Finnaly http://superuser.com/questions/284527/where-are-the-vista-win7-volume-mixer-settings-stored which shows where that data is stored in registry, clearable.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Thanks for all the info. Although they are very helpful, they didn't solve my problem. At the end I updated my audio driver and everything is working fine now.